# Unable to display base64 image in react native on iOS

Tags: react-native, base64

I am trying to display a base64 image from my api but get a white space in place of the image, its work fine on android - any ideas?

```
<Image
                source={{ uri: Images.slider.slider1 }}
                PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator />}
                style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                />
```

Images.slider.slider1:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAXcAAAFbCAIAAAChzFnkAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeJx8vVuyLEmuKwZ6ZPW5pvlPST8y03Skc/tUOvRBAGTkrtZq611rZUb4gw8QpHt41P/5f/3fIC9574V/qqp/IUmAharTnx8CIADUAemL9QsB/QFcgH0BWFWFes6pQqFI9n8Bog5Q3dc551R1U9X9FwAUCuhuusnuDn1joQrFH
```

Comment: happened with me in old version of react-native, what is your react-native version?

Comment: "react-native": "0.62.0",

Comment: i had same prob i upgraded to a newer version and it solved, i see my project has now 0.63, you can try upgrading react-native version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known issue in react native 0.62 ,
kindly check this link [Github RN](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28583#issuecomment-614239427) .

What basically was done in the PR was :

```
For anyone else that comes across this just change the version of Flipper in the podfile to

  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.37.0'
```

do let me know in case of any concerns